# Maximum-average prefix of binomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

For $k\in\mathbb N$, let
$$
f(k)=\max_{j\in\{1,\dots,k\}}\left\{\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}\binom{k}{i}}{j} \right\}.
$$
Is there a way to express $f(k)$ explicitly?
If not, what is $\lim_{k\to\infty}f(k)$?

Answer (score 2):

The limit is easy, since $f(k) \geq \frac{2^k-1}{k}$ (take $j = k$), hence $\lim_{k \to \infty} f(k) = \infty$.